# Permutation matrix inverse in $\{ P, P^2, P^3, \dots, P^n \}$

Tags: matrices, permutations, permutation-matrices

Let $P$ be an $ n \times n$ permutation matrix. Does the list $\{ P, P^2, P^3, \dots, P^n \}$ contain $P^{-1}$ ? If so, any proof without using group theory?

Comment: Consider the permutation $\sigma = (12345)(67).$   While this permutation has $7$ elements, it is of order $10.$   i.e. $\sigma^{-1} = \sigma^9.$  While this is a group-theoretic notation, we could just as easily write this up as a $7\times 7$ matrix.

Comment: First show this is true for cyclic permutations. Then generalize using block matrices. You should try to puzzle out why this is the same approach @DougM suggested.

Comment: Thanks. This means that the given list does not always contain $P^{-1}$or the identity matrix.